# google.script.run.withSuccessHandler() return null value

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I need to retrieve the data send by this function and display it in an html table

```
//Function to get All Patients List...
const getAllPatientsList = () => {
  try {
    const responseProcessorSheet = dataColSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('ReponsesProcessor');

    if (responseProcessorSheet.getRange('A2').isBlank()) return;

    const iDIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'ID');
    const isCompleteIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'IsComplete');
    const isApprovedIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'isApproved');
    const isRejectedIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'isRejected');
    const rejReasonsIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'RejectionReasons');
    const isSheduledIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'IsScheduled');
    const toBeReScheduledIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'ToBeReScheduled');
    const dentalCodesIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'DentalCodes');
    const surgeryDateIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'Surgery Date');
    const referringOfficeNameIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'Referring Office Name');
    const patientFirstNameIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'Patient First Name');
    const patientLastNameIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'Patient Last Name');
    const genderAtBirthIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'Gender at Birth');
    const patientDateOfBirthIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Patient's Date of Birth`);
    const wisdomTeethNumbersIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Wisdom Teeth Numbers to be Extracted`);
    const otherTeethNumbersIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, 'Other Teeth Numbers to be Extracted');
    const responsiblePartyFirstNameIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Responsible Party's First Name`);
    const responsiblePartyLastNameIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Responsible Party's Last Name `);
    const responsiblePartyPhoneNumberIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Responsible Party's Phone Number`);
    const responsiblePartyEmailIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Responsible Party's Email`);
    const patientXRayIndex = getColumnIndexFromName(responseProcessorSheet, `Patient  X-Ray `);
    const allPatientData = [];

    const sheetValues = responseProcessorSheet.getRange(2, 1, responseProcessorSheet.getLastRow() - 1, responseProcessorSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

    for (let data of sheetValues) {
      if (data[iDIndex - 1] === '' || data[iDIndex - 1] === null) continue;

      let temp = {};
      temp['iD'] = data[iDIndex - 1];
      temp['isComplete'] = data[isCompleteIndex - 1];
      temp['isApproved'] = data[isApprovedIndex - 1];
      temp['isRejected'] = data[isRejectedIndex - 1];
      temp['rejReasons'] = data[rejReasonsIndex - 1];
      temp['isSheduled'] = data[isSheduledIndex - 1];
      temp['toBeReScheduled'] = data[toBeReScheduledIndex - 1];
      temp['dentalCodes'] = data[dentalCodesIndex - 1];
      temp['surgeryDate'] = data[surgeryDateIndex - 1];
      temp['referringOfficeName'] = data[referringOfficeNameIndex - 1];
      temp['patientFirstName'] = data[patientFirstNameIndex - 1];
      temp['patientLastName'] = data[patientLastNameIndex - 1];
      temp['genderAtBirth'] = data[genderAtBirthIndex - 1];
      temp['patientDateOfBirth'] = data[patientDateOfBirthIndex - 1];
      temp['wisdomTeethNumbers'] = data[wisdomTeethNumbersIndex - 1];
      temp['otherTeethNumbers'] = data[otherTeethNumbersIndex - 1];
      temp['responsiblePartyFirstName'] = data[responsiblePartyFirstNameIndex - 1];
      temp['responsiblePartyLastName'] = data[responsiblePartyLastNameIndex - 1];
      temp['responsiblePartyPhoneNumber'] = data[responsiblePartyPhoneNumberIndex - 1];
      temp['responsiblePartyEmail'] = data[responsiblePartyEmailIndex - 1];
      temp['patientXRay'] = data[patientXRayIndex - 1];

      allPatientData.push(temp);
    };
    console.log("Patients récupérés :", allPatientData);
    return allPatientData;
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log(`getAllPatientsListError: ${error.message}`);
    return `getAllPatientsListError: ${error.message}`;
  };
 
};
```

server side data is returned in this format. i got this from server side logs.

```
    [ { iD: 1683945240392,
    isComplete: '',
    isApproved: '',
    isRejected: '',
    rejReasons: '',
    isSheduled: '',
    toBeReScheduled: '',
    dentalCodes: '',
    surgeryDate: '',
    referringOfficeName: 'Office 1',
    patientFirstName: 'laura',
    patientLastName: 'WAx',
    genderAtBirth: 'Female',
    patientDateOfBirth: Tue Jun 13 1995 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
    wisdomTeethNumbers: 16,
    otherTeethNumbers: '12,5,6',
    responsiblePartyFirstName: 'Tom',
    responsiblePartyLastName: 'Jerry',
    responsiblePartyPhoneNumber: '+22996764654',
    responsiblePartyEmail: 'blockchaindevxinxi@gmail.com',
    patientXRay: 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NZKUpQ1uevK2QI26n-E4VWSvfju7aPvW' },
  { iD: 1683945737559,
    isComplete: '',
    isApproved: '',
    isRejected: '',
    rejReasons: '',
    isSheduled: '',
    toBeReScheduled: '',
    dentalCodes: '',
    surgeryDate: '',
    referringOfficeName: 'Office2',
    patientFirstName: 'ken',
    patientLastName: 'Smith',
    genderAtBirth: 'Male',
    patientDateOfBirth: Thu Aug 08 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time),
    wisdomTeethNumbers: 'All 4 Wisdom Teeth (1, 16, 17, 32)',
    otherTeethNumbers: '5,6',
    responsiblePartyFirstName: 'Lebron',
    responsiblePartyLastName: 'Jordan',
    responsiblePartyPhoneNumber: 22996764654,
    responsiblePartyEmail: 'blockchaindevxinxi@gmail.com',
    patientXRay: 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I3Wsz6XA69f8h9JlAy3gZ8RcnfdAyHSO' } ]
```

I wrote this function on the navigatur side to be able to retrieve the data

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  init();
});

function init() {
  console.log("Avant appel à google.script.run");
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayPatients).getAllPatientsList();
}

function displayPatients(patients) {
  var tableBody = document.querySelector('#data_table_all tbody');
  tableBody.innerHTML = ''; // Efface les données précédentes du tableau (s'il y en a)
  console.log(patients);
  if (patients && patients.length) { // Vérifie que la variable patients est définie et contient des éléments
    console.log("Longueur du tableau patients :", patients.length);
    patients.forEach(function(patient) {
      console.log("Patient en cours de traitement :", patient);
      let row = document.createElement('tr');

      let nameCell = document.createElement('td');
      nameCell.textContent = patient.patientFirstName + ' ' + patient.patientLastName;
      row.appendChild(nameCell);
      console.log("Prénom du patient :", patient.patientFirstName);
      var ageCell = document.createElement('td');
      var birthDate = new Date(patient.patientDateOfBirth);
      var today = new Date();
      var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
      ageCell.textContent = age;
      row.appendChild(ageCell);

      var addressCell = document.createElement('td');
      addressCell.textContent = patient.referringOfficeName;
      row.appendChild(addressCell);

      // ... Ajoutez d'autres cellules de données selon vos besoins

      tableBody.appendChild(row);
    });
  } else {
    // Si patients est null ou ne contient pas d'éléments, affichez un message d'erreur dans le tableau
    var errorRow = document.createElement('tr');
    var errorCell = document.createElement('td');
    errorCell.colSpan = 3; // Étend la cellule sur trois colonnes pour occuper tout l'espace disponible
    errorCell.textContent = 'Aucun patient trouvé';
    errorRow.appendChild(errorCell);
    tableBody.appendChild(errorRow);
  }
}
```

the getAllPatientsList() function was returning an object that was not recieved by the displayPatients() function's parameter and I got a null instead as you see my browser console, can you help me please
[image]

Comment: no I already tried something like that but nothing my function on the browser side looks correct but it just retrieves an empty table

Comment: i had just figured out can you do one more thing.. share me your browser console... to my... m[dot]naeem66622@outlook[dot]com... replace [dot] with . or you can attach you picture to the answer too.. choice is yours

Comment: i cant run google.script... i had tested your data returned by server by storing it into variable... it works in my case with no error and got data into table on a webpage... that's why i want to see the console of your browser

Comment: I sent you the picture of the browser on your email with uhoungbo@gmail.com

Comment: send me your codeApppanel.js file too to my email

Comment: i already send it you

Comment: Can you please share your sheets so we can replicate your concern easily.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uOVjy2nlINsxnt9LzoxkBZvqerSbb3ZyNomwra5ReYg/edit#gid=0

Comment: unfortunately, I can't access

Comment: you should be able to access it

Comment: Can you please specify your goal and the UI workflow? Also, could you provide information on how we can determine which table each user should use?

Comment: all the data must be in the table all and then there is a filter that is made to put the data in the approved schduled reject tables according to the boolean isapproved, irejected and isscheduled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What you did wrong?

In the context of your code, you were encountering an issue where the `getAllPatientsList()` function was returning an object that was not recieved by the `displayPatients()` function's parameter. The problem is that you are trying to return an **unacceptable type** of data to client-side. Functions called via `google.script.run` have restrictions on what they can return (for example, you should avoid `Date` instances).

**Restricted types**

Currently, you can't return (take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#parameters) for detailed explanation of restrictions):

1. `Date` instances;
2. any `Function`;
3. DOM elements (though `<form>` is permitted);

### So what we can do?

To fix this issue, you can use a workaround that involves serializing and then deserializing the object using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse(), respectively. By doing so, you forced a regular JavaScript serialization that avoid the issue.

You just need to do three steps

1. change `return allPatientData;` to `return JSON.stringify(allPatientData);`
2. change parameter `function displayPatients(patients)` to `function displayPatients(data)`
3. add line in the top of the fuction displayPatients `var patients = JSON.parse(data);`

Here's the code snippet that fixed the issue:

```
function getAllPatientsList() {
  // ...
  return JSON.stringify(allPatientData);
}

function displayPatients(data) {
  var patients = JSON.parse(data);
  // ...
}
```